# Inserting a record from a mongoose model.statics function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a static function on a mongoose "log" module, which would allow me to write a message as a log entry.

How do I access the model from within the static function? Can I use `this.model` like below?  I don't want to simply use native MongoDB insert command, because I want the model to validate the input, etc.

```
// ... schema defined above...
var Log = mongoose.model('Log', LogModelSchema)
Log.statics.log = function(message) {
    var x = new this.model({message: message})
    x.save()
        .then(() => { .. do something .. }
        .catch((err) => { .. handle  err .. }
}
```

Is this the way it's supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work like this using this.create:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const logSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  message: String
});

logSchema.statics.log = function(message) {
  this.create({ message: message })
    .then(doc => console.log(doc))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("Log", logSchema);
```

Now you can use this in your routes like this:

```
Log.log("test");
```

or just return promise from statics:

```
logSchema.statics.log = function(message) {
  return this.create({ message: message });
};
```

And use like this:

```
const Log = require("../models/log");

router.get("/log", (req, res) => {
  Log.log("test")
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      res.send("ok");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("not ok");
    });
});
```

Comment: Will `.create()` process all the pre/post middleware?  Also, do I have to do a `save()` or does it happen automatically?

Comment: @RyanGriggs  .create will call any validators/hooks declared on your schema.

Comment: Also, the static function is created on the Schema, instead of the Model.  Why?  And how would I call this from another module?  would it be like ` var log = require('log'); log.schema.log(..)` or would it be `log.log(...)`? Are Schema statics available from the model object?

Comment: I tested this code in a sample route like this: Log.log("test"), and it created the document. Please see the updated answer how to use it

Comment: @RyanGriggs  create is on the model: see the docs please: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create